# Let C18 throw a compiler error

Tags: c, compiler-errors, pic, mplab, mplab-c18

Is there a way to let the C18 compiler throw an own, customized error message during compiling?

For example, consider a situation with two user-defined settings:

```
#define SETTING_A 0x80
#define SETTING_B 0x3f
```

Assume these settings can't be *both* `0x00`. Is there a way to let the compiler throw an error (or at least a warning) when the user sets both settings to `0x00`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider using `#if` and `#error`:

```
#if (SETTING_A == 0) && (SETTING_B == 0)
#error SETTING_A and SETTING_B can't both be 0!
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what C18 does or doesn't support, but you should try the `#error` directive.